# In a VSCode extension how can I pull up a Markdown document only in preview mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions

I am working on a VSCode extension that runs an analysis on some solidity code and then produces an analysis report in markdown for that. I'd like the markdown to appear only in preview mode. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) api, and provide your content as the html string.

Comment: Ultimately this is probably the solution for the litany of things I would like to do. For doing just a preview of Markdown it seems like a work. I'll try it though and let you and others know how it works. If you want though to give code as to how to do this, that would be appreciated.